# the implementation of the Karatsuba algorithm, the method only counts the small numbers true, but the big answer is not correct, what's the problem?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bigint, karatsuba

The implementation of the Karatsuba algorithm, the method only counts the small numbers true, but the big answer is not correct,   what's the problem?

```js
var x = "1685287499328328297814655639278583667919355849391453456921116729";
var y = "7114192848577754587969744626558571536728983167954552999895348492";

function karatsuba(x, y) {
    if (x.length < 2 && y.length < 2) {
        return BigInt(parseInt(x) * parseInt(y));
    }
    var m = Math.min(x.length, y.length);
    var m2 = m / 2;
    var a = BigInt(x.substring(0, m2));
    var b = BigInt(x.substring(m2));
    var c = BigInt(y.substring(0, m2));
    var d = BigInt(y.substring(m2));
    var ac = a * c;
    var bd = b * d;
    var sum = (a + b) * (c + d) - ac - bd;

    return BigInt(Math.pow(10, m)) * ac + BigInt(Math.pow(10, m2)) * sum + bd;
}

console.log(karatsuba(x, y));
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add your actual code to the question rather than a screenshot of your code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking `Math.pow` is very suspicious. According to [documentation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.pow), it

> Returns an implementation-dependent approximation to the result of raising x to the power y.

You don't want any *approximations* in Karatzuba.

Answer (score 1):

```
return BigInt(parseInt(x) * parseInt(y));
```

It defeats the point to multiply large things together before constructing a BigInt.

Comment: (I think I see your point, but the code quoted is used when *both* factors are shorter than two digits (not large by my book). But then, there is scaling using the `*` operator …)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [user58697's word of warning about floating point arithmetic in general and transcendental functions in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54208320/3789665):

You use `m2` in splitting the numbers, but `m` (too) in scaling before/in combination/"(polynomial) evaluation".

> You need to use `2*m2`.